# Cannot render animation? Panel issues?

Tags: rendering

I can't get my animation to render, the panel doesn't look like the tutorial's.[image]

[image]

The bottom one is what it's supposed to look like, but the top image is what it looks like for me. This is probably an easy fix I just need help.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the game engine. To render use blender render or cycles.

[image]